# Question about a weird problem in functions in C language?

Tags: c, function

When calling the function **billCalculator** and giving it **getExtraDrinks** and **getExtraSandwiches** as arguments ,for some reason it is taking the 2nd argument first.

This is the code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<time.h>

//Waseem Qasem Agha - 20210374 - S:18

displayWelcome() {
    printf("*******************************\n* Welcome to CS151 Restaurant *\n*******************************\n\n");
}

int getExtraDrinks() {
    int extraDrinks;
    printf("How many extra drinks do you want to get?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &extraDrinks);
    return extraDrinks;
}
int getExtraSandwiches() {
    int extraSandwiches;
    printf("How many extra sandwiches do you want to get?\n");
    scanf_s("%d", &extraSandwiches);
    return extraSandwiches;
}

float billCalculator(int extraDrinks,int extraSandwiches) {
    float totalPrice;
    totalPrice = 2.00 + (extraDrinks * 0.5) + (extraSandwiches * 1.25);
    return totalPrice;
}

int main() {
    displayWelcome();
    printf("Total price = %.2f JD", billCalculator(getExtraDrinks(),getExtraSandwiches()));

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please don't tag spam. C is not the same as C++, any more than a car and a cat are the same because they start with the same letter. Tags have relevance and meaning here, and  should not be added unless they actually apply to your post. I've removed the invalid C++ tag, as it clearly does not apply to your question.

Comment: There is no guarantee on the order in which function parameters are evaluated. Just store them in variables if the order is important.

Comment: This shows your assumptions and expectations are incorrect.

Comment: @chtz That should be an answer.

Comment: Come on, let's not be snarky about this. It's not obvious behavior for beginners. Even I had labored under the idea for many years that args were evaluated right to left (to support varargs functions).

Answer (score 3):

The order of evaluation of arguments to a function is *unspecified*.  This means (among other things) that if two arguments involve function calls, there is no guarantee which one will be called first.

This is formally spelled out in section 6.5.2.2p10 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) regarding function calls:

> **There is a sequence point after the evaluations of the function
> designator and the actual arguments but before the actual call.** Every
> evaluation in the calling function (including other function calls)
> that is not otherwise specifically sequenced before or after the
> execution of the body of the called function is indeterminately
> sequenced with respect to the execution of the called function

So because there is no sequence point between the evaluation of each argument, they can be evaluated in any order.

If you need the functions to be called in a specific order, call them in separate statements which assign the return values to variables, then pass those variables to the function.